# How to update metadata media file from azure storage or media serviceazure

Tags: c#, azure, metadata, id3, id3v2

I would like to change media file metadata from medias hosted in my azure storage like "author", "artist" and others tags.

****Attribute   ID3v1.x ID3v2.2 ID3v2.3/v2.4****

Author  Artist  TP1 TPE1

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743220(v=vs.85).aspx

By Now, I change the media metadata once the user uploads the video by using an encoder media Job with custom XML preset configuration. But I would like to change the metadata of already uploaded and encoded videos.
Is there any way to change the media's metadata (already in our Azure Stroage) without re-encoding the media again?

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Media Services uses Azure Blob Storage to store media assets. Since ID3 tags are metadata bytes appended to the end of media files, the tags themselves are stored together in the blob container and there is no API to change them directly and one would need to fetch them and then edit the metadata.

However, note that changing ID3 tags and other metadata is an operation which is not costly as it affects the media file container and not the internal encoded media. This means there is no need to transcode or re-encode media just for changing the tag. The various operations described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758036(v=vs.85).aspx) will change the metadata but will not re-encode the media itself.

You might also find the following SDK useful for working with media assets:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-media-services-extensions